# Commenting on my code

Tags: c++

I'm having difficulty commenting on my code for a blackjack app for c++.  I have coded it but now I am confused as to what to put in for comments, my instructor is frugal when it comes to commenting.

Thanks for any and all help! :)

here is my code:

```
#include <iostream> // in/out for form
#include <ctime> // uses time for randomizing
#include <Windows.h> //

using namespace std; // prevents redundancey of ::STD


    char enter[1]; //
    int hand[52] = {}, dealer[52]; // array of 52 for 52 cards that holds zero

    int GetScore(int param) // function prototype that calls getscore
    {
        int score = 0; // 
        int temp[52]; //

        if(param == 0) for(int i = 0; i < 52; i++) temp[i] = hand[i];  //
        if(param == 1) for(int i = 0; i < 52; i++) temp[i] = dealer[i]; //

        for(int i = 0; i < 52; i++) //
        {
            if(temp[i] == 0) break; //

            if(temp[i] != 11)
            {
                score += temp[i];
            }
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < 52; i++) // simple loop to ....
        {
            if(temp[i] == 0) break;

            if(temp[i] == 11)
            {
                if(temp[i] + score <= 21)
                {
                    score += 11;
                }
                else
                {
                    score += 1;
                }
            }
        }

        return score;
    }

    void ShowDealersHand(int show) //
    {
        cout << "\n                          Dealer's hand: "; //

        if(show == 1) //
        {
            if(dealer[0] == 11)
            {
                cout << "A [Not Shown]";
            }
            else
            {
                cout << dealer[0] << " [Not Shown]";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < 52; i++)
            {
                if(dealer[i] == 0) break;

                if(dealer[i] == 11)
                {
                    cout << "A ";
                }
                else
                {
                    cout << dealer[i] << " ";
                }
            }
        }
    }

    void Blackjack()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++) //
        {
            int num, temp;

            if(hand[0] == 0) temp = 0;
            else temp = 1;

            num = rand() % 10 + 2;
            hand[temp] = num;

            num = rand() % 10 + 2;
            dealer[temp] = num;
        }

        ShowDealersHand(1); //
        cout << endl << endl << "                          Your hand: "; //

        for(int i = 0; i < 52; i++) //
        {
            if(hand[i] == 0) break;

            if(hand[i] == 11)
            {
                cout << "A ";
            }
            else
            {
                cout << hand[i] << " ";
            }
        }

        cout << endl << "                          Your score: " << GetScore(0) << endl << endl;

        while(GetScore(0) <= 21)
        {
            cout << "                          Hit(h) or stand(s): ";

            cin >> enter;

            if(strcmp(enter, "h") == 0)
            {
                int card = rand() % 10 + 2;

                for(int i = 0; i < 52; i++)
                {
                    if(hand[i] == 0)
                    {
                        hand[i] = card;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                cout << "                          Your hand: ";

                for(int i = 0; i < 52; i++)
                {
                    if(hand[i] == 0) break;

                    if(hand[i] == 11)
                    {
                        cout << "A ";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cout << hand[i] << " ";
                    }
                }

                cout << endl << "                          Your score: " << GetScore(0) << endl << endl;

                if(GetScore(0) > 21)
                {
                    cout << "                           - ..BUST.. -" << endl ;
                    cout << "\n                         - !!House Wins!! -";
                    goto end;
                    break;
                }
            }
            else if(strcmp(enter, "s") == 0)
            {
                cout << endl;

                break;
            }

            system("pause > nul");
        }

        Sleep(2000);

        ShowDealersHand(0);
        cout << endl << "                          Dealer score: " << GetScore(1) << endl << endl;

        if(GetScore(1) < GetScore(0))
        {
            while(GetScore(1) < 17 && GetScore(0) <= 21)
            {
                Sleep(2000);

                int card = rand() % 10 + 2;

                for(int i = 0; i < 52; i++)
                {
                    if(dealer[i] == 0)
                    {
                        dealer[i] = card;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                cout << "                          Dealer's hand: ";

                for(int i = 0; i < 52; i++)
                {
                    if(dealer[i] == 0) break;

                    if(dealer[i] == 11)
                    {
                        cout << "A ";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cout << dealer[i] << " ";
                    }
                }

                cout << endl << "                          Dealer score: " << GetScore(1) << endl << endl;

                if(GetScore(1) >= GetScore(0)) break;
            }
        }

        end:
        if(GetScore(1) > GetScore(0) && GetScore(1) <= 21)
        {
            cout << "                          - !!House Wins!! -";
        }
        else if(GetScore(1) == GetScore(0) && GetScore(0) <= 21)
        {
            cout << "                          * Tie * - !!House Wins!! -";
        }
        else if(GetScore(0) <= 21)
        {
            cout << "                                - !!!You win!!! -"; // outputs if you win
        }

        system("pause > nul");
        system("cls");
    }

    void main() // no return on main for form to start
    {
        srand((unsigned int)time(0)); // randomizer unasigned initializer

        cout << "                    *-*-*-*-*Zachattack's Blackjack*-*-*-*-*" << endl << endl; // Name of program outputs to user

        Blackjack();
    }
```

Comment: Don't use "retarded" like this, please.

Comment: You know what you did in the code. So, why not just explain that.

Comment: you are trying to "overcomment" in my opinion; you should comment code sections that are hard to crack or to add a comment where you display the general idea of the algorithm

Answer (score 4):

As they are, you comments are useless. Take, for example, this:

```
int hand[52] = {}, dealer[52]; // array of 52 for 52 cards that holds zero
```

Anyone that uses C/C++ is expected to know what that line is doing, without having to read the comment.

Instead of commenting what your code does ("this line declares an int"), comment why the code does what it does (what you were thinking when you wrote that code), or, if the algorithm is complicated, comment on how it does something, or document how to use your functions.

For example, your `GetScore` function takes has a parameter called `param`. I've no idea what values I am expected to give to `param`, so you should explain it: "when param is 1, this happens, when it is 0, that happens".

Another example: in your code you have a line `Sleep(2000)`. Why did you use that function? Explain it in a comment:

```
// Sleep 2 seconds to make the game more exciting
Sleep(2000);
```

Always assume that the person reading your code knows how to use the language. Never assume that the person reading your code is able to understand your way of thinking about a certain problem.

Answer (score 2):

Comments should explain **why**, not what.

So your comment for `using namespace std;` is unnecessary, because any C++ programmer will already know what the `using` keyword does.

However, for the GetScore() function, you've omitted to give the rules for totalling the score.

The comments should add value, not just duplicate things that are obvious from even a cursory look at the code.

Assume the person reading the code is familiar with the programming environment, but wasn't party to what was going on in your mind as you wrote it.

Here's an example I sometimes use - a piece of code with useless comments (can you work out what is going on here, and why?):

```
// Is the new selection end above the selection start?
if newSelEnd.Line < FSelection.SelStart.Line then
begin
  // Is the selection start at the left margin and above the selection end?
  if (FSelection.SelStart.Line < FSelection.SelEnd.Line) and
     (FSelection.SelStart.Column = 0) then
  begin
    // Move the selection start down one line
    Inc(FSelection.SelStart.Line);
```

And with helpful comments:

```
if newSelEnd.Line < FSelection.SelStart.Line then
begin
  // The new selection end is above the selection start, so will become the
  // top of the new selection.
  if (FSelection.SelStart.Line < FSelection.SelEnd.Line) and
     (FSelection.SelStart.Column = 0) then
  begin
    // The start of the selection was at the top of the old selection and the
    // new line is above this, so the selection is about to change direction.
    // Since the start column is 0 we assume the original selection was an
    // entire line, so we keep the original line selected by moving the start
    // position down one line.
    Inc(FSelection.SelStart.Line);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Function/method purpose with parameters purposes
2. Magic numbers

Those are my most important rules about commenting. Optional is "why am I iterating/what am I looking for" about loops. Magic numbers is every declaration/condition that uses const values like `GetScore(0) <= 21`, or `hand[52]`.

Those are places that should be commented even for yourself... It feels realy good when you look at your code after year or more and still read it without any problem.

Comment: Much better is to declare constants for your magic numbers. Then you can write `if (GetScore(0) < bust)` or `hand[cards_in_deck]`. Makes errors much easier to spot.

Comment: forgot to mention that. But in case of "single use" magic numbers i prefer comment

Comment: in my experience, single use magic numbers never remain like that

Comment: Even a single use magic number can be replaced with a comment. See my edited reply.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the other answers, often, it is a good idea to get rid of a comment by replacing it with a named function:

```
// Find top-scorers:
for (Iter it=scorers.begin(), end=scorers.end(); it!=end; ++it) {
    ...
    {
        top.push_back (*it);
    }
}
```

Instead, do:

```
const std::vector<Scorer> top = find_top_scorers (scorers.begin(), 
                                                  scorers.end());
```

This decreases miss-maintenance (comments are not enforced and may get out-of-date) and reusability. Personally, I always endeavour for commentless code, as I am sick of out-of-date comments, when possible and sane.

Of course, in the example above, you should probably use `std::partial_sort`, `std::partition` or `std::stable_partition`.

---

Also, magic numbers should be replaced by constants instead, with the same argumentation about miss-maintenance and reusability:

```
const float x = radius * 3.14159...; // radius * pi

const float pi = 3.14159...,
             x = radius * pi;
```

Comment: why global variables instead of macros?

Comment: @KamilKlimek: What do you mean?

Comment: I would just know why you're using global/local variables instead of macros. Simple question...

Comment: @KamilKlimek: Oh, I did not. That was just exemplary code without any positional context. About macros: They are almost never beneficial to better alternatives in C++; e.g. they have no scope and pollute the space of identifiers globally, you cannot escape from them. Stackoverflow has more infos about them.